# Twilio - How to update Task attributes defined in IVR flow for an inbound call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am wondering how to update **event.TaskAttributes.*variable*** value of a current task. I thought it's straight forward from the example by Twilio but I am not seeing any change If I followed the same and try to set/update a value of a specific attribute (defined in IVR voice flow widget).

https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/task#action-update

For example, there is an attribute called **language** which is a gather input digits field in IVR flow and at some point in the execution (while the caller is in waiting queue), we would like to update it to a different value. I tried via postman but it does nothing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/WSXXXXXXX/Tasks/WTXXXXXX

{
"attributes": {
"language": "6"
}
}

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postman use url-encoded format. The request should be encoded. Use 'Attributes' in place of 'attributes'. I am attaching a sample cURL request, this might be helpful

```
    curl -X POST \
  https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/WS...../Tasks/WTXXXX...... \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'Attributes=%7B%22test2%22%3A%201%7D'
```